¿Cómo soluciono el scroll persistente?
Cuando scrolleo en una página de mi sitio web de ReactJS y cambio a otra, en lugar de mostrarse al principio de la misma se muestra en la posición en que quedó la página anterior. Es decir, el scrolling se está produciendo en todas las páginas a la vez. Se trata de un sitio web muy sencillo que apenas estoy empezando a desarrollar. Alguien tiene alguna idea de cuál podría ser el problema?
Envío los dos componentes que manejan el cambio de página.
Mi componente principal es así:
import './App.css';
import './components/Carrusel/Carrusel.css'; 
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar/NavBar';
import Inicio from './components/Inicio/Inicio';
import Departamentos from './components/Departamentos/Departamentos';
import Ubicacion from './components/Ubicacion/Ubicacion';
import Contacto from './components/Contacto/Contacto';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';


function App() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Esta función flecha maneja el evento de desplazamiento
    const handleScroll = () => {
      // Obtiene la cantidad de desplazamiento vertical de la página
      const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      const triggerPoint = 80; // Punto de desplazamiento que activa el cambio de visibilidad del NavBar
  
      console.log("Scroll Top:", scrollTop); // Agregar esta línea para depurar
  
      // Si el desplazamiento es mayor que el punto de activación
      if (scrollTop > triggerPoint) {
        setIsVisible(true); // Establece isVisible en true para mostrar el NavBar
      } else { // Si el desplazamiento es menor que el punto de activación
        setIsVisible(false); // Establece isVisible en false para ocultar el NavBar
      }
    };
  
    // Agrega un event listener para el evento de desplazamiento
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  
    // Limpia el event listener cuando el componente se desmonta
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []); // El array vacío [] asegura que el efecto se ejecute solo una vez, equivalente a componentDidMount
  

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar isVisible={isVisible} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Inicio />} />
          <Route path="/departamentos" element={<Departamentos />} />
          <Route path="/ubicacion" element={<Ubicacion />} />
          <Route path="/contacto" element={<Contacto />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

Y mi componente navbar asi:
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavBar.css';

const NavBar = ({ isVisible }) => {
  return (
    <nav className={`NavBar ${isVisible ? 'fixed' : ''}`}>
      <h2>Puerto Bueno</h2>
      <ul className="nav justify-content-end">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Inicio</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/departamentos" className="nav-link">Departamentos</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/ubicacion" className="nav-link">Ubicación</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/contacto" className="nav-link">Contacto</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;


Suena a un tema de componentes y ruteo, pero sin ver lo que estas haciendo dificil ayudarte...

Fijate por las dudas que tu url no tenga un ancla que te este haciendo scroll al cambiar de página. Por ejemplo si tu url al cambiar de pagina es: http://localhost:3000/ruta/#algo Esa url te lleva a la pagina "/ruta" y hace scroll hasta un html con id "algo" En caso de no ser ese el error si queres manda un trozo de tu codigo asi podemos revisarlo!

Revisé y no parece ser el problema. Si pudieras revisar el código te lo agradecería mucho.
